# Lollipop SDCard Document write

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, document, android-sdcard

I have a third party library which accepts a File object and modifies the same.
Now after getting the permission to SD card using

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
```

And selecting SD card root.

then user browses through the files which he wants to modify. Now this 
file's path/ file object I need to pass to the third party library class.

```
 DocumentFile documentFile = DocumentFile.fromFile(file);
 String documentURI = documentFile.getUri().toString();
 MP3File mp3File = null;

 documentFile = DocumentFile.fromFile(file);
 mp3File = new MP3File(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Here MP3File class accepts file path. but this class does not have any Document constructor.

Can i convert document to a writable file which i can replace with the original file? Or is there any simpler solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now after getting the permission to SD card using... And selecting SD card root.

There is no requirement for the user to choose any particular document. The document *might* be on removable storage, or external storage, or Google Drive, or Dropbox, or a file server, or anywhere else the user can access.

> Now this file's path/ file object I need to pass to the third party library class.

There is no "path/file object" for that document.

> Here MP3File class accepts file path

Either:

- Find a better library, one that accepts an `InputStream` and/or `OutputStream`, so you can work with the document where it resides, or
- Use Java I/O to copy the document's contents to a local file that you control, then pass that file to the library